# Add a button to cart page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

guys I am trying to add a button in the Shopping Cart page named "Save Cart" near "Update Cart Button".

### I have the following folder structure:

Mustard

-- SavedCart

-------Block

-----------Cart.php

Setup

---InstallSchema.php

etc

--di.xml

--module.xml

view

---frontend

-----layout

---------checkout_cart_index.xml

template

---save_cart_button.phtml

### So here are the codes

### Cart.php

```
<?php

namespace Mustard\SavedCart\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;


class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart
{

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
    }


}
```

### di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart"
            type="Mustard\SavedCart\Block\Cart"/>
</config>
```

### module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Mustard_SavedCart" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
</config>
```

### checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart" 
        template="Mustard_SavedCart::save_cart_button.phtml"/>
</body>
</page>
```

### save_cart_button.phtml

```
<form>
<button type="button" name="saveCart">
        Save Cart
</button>
</form>
```

now with this configuration in place when in run magento , i get a blank page at **localhost/magento21/checkout/cart**

**Can anyone help me Please ? 
I need to add a button in the shopping cart page near the Update Shopping Cart button.**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally solve the issue. I Over rided couple of template files and blocks that were child components of `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart` block. You can find those related templates and blocks that are needed to be over rided inside the `checkout_cart_index.xml` file.
After all this i was able to get that button on the cart page.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the code fot Cart.php file? Thanks